# Passing data from Pure Php(Native) to framework Php (CI)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good day,

I have written a script using Native (Core) Php. In the native Php
I'm trying to pass a certain data to another Php application which is created under framework (Codeigniter) php. I've been searching everywhere for an answer about this dilemma.

To cut it short I have a line in my pure php like this one

```
_cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX('0919XXXXXXX');
```

where _cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a function inside CI controller and the 0919XXXXXXX I want to pass.

It's like I'm just calling a function from CI and bluntly using it in my Native Php. (Little knowledge in CI here and me studying in Malaysia to learn this one is not so good because of personal problems.)

It there a way where I just can pass the data to CI and CI will do the processing.

Its like this

```
Data ----> Native Php ----> Pass to CI---> CI process the data
```

It's like Im creating a gateway or a middle system to gather data and just throw them to CI for processing.

Thanks and hope to be enlightened.

Comment: you want to access this through URL or something else

Comment: Yes URL is one of the ideas I have in mind and if there's also another way maybe I can ask you how? Thanks for the quick check on my question.

Comment: You would like to call a function which is in core php file , You want to call this function from CI Application to get data from Core PHP application  and use it CI Application right ?

Comment: No sir, it's the other way around. The function is on CI application and I want to use that function/s in core php

Comment: define a route in route.php file in CI

and  call this function using url http://localhost/application/_yourFunction/ypurparameter

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your Route File

```
$route['api/(:any)'] = 'api/_cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/$1';
```

Where **Api** is controller and **_cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX** is your Function name in controller

This is your function in controller and $num is your argument

```
public function _cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX($num){
     //Your Code Here 
}
```

You can access it from browser 
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/api/7878875554

if you want to access this in your core php application you can use 
file_get_contents, or CURL

Comment: router of the controller?

Comment: $route['api/(:any)'] = 'api/_cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/$1'; 
where api is controller and  _cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX is function